# Bash remove every occurrence after first in string

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove everything after a `specific_string` in a path string in Bash. I've tried using `sed` to no avail so far.

```
variable="specific_string"
input_string="/path/to/some/specific_string/specific_string.something/specific_string.something-else"
output=$(sed 's/$variable//' $input_string)
```

Output should be `"/path/to/some/specific_string/"`

Would be better if I didn't have to use commands such as `sed`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problems

There are many problems

- Variables are not evaluated inside single quotes. `'s/$variable//'` will be treated as a literal string, which does *not* contain `specific_string`
- `sed` can modify text from files or STDIN, but not text given via parameters. With `sed 's/...//' $input_string` the `/path/to/some/specific_string/.../file` is opened and its content is read, instead of the path itself.
- `s/string//` deletes *only* `string`, not the words afterwards.

Also remember to double quote your variables. `cmd $variable` is dangerous if the variable contains spaces. `cmd "$variable"` is safe.

## Sed Solution

```
output="$(sed "s/$variable.*/$variable/" <<< "$input_string")"
```

## GNU Grep Solution

```
output="$(grep -Po "^.*?$variable" <<< "$input_string")"
```

## Pure Bash Solution

```
output="${input_string%%$variable*}$variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove everything after "specific_string" it will remove the "/" also as it does with the following example:

```
output=$(echo $input_string|sed "s/${variable}.*$/${variable}/")
```

Answer (score 1):

try with simple sed:

```
variable="specific_string"
input_string="/path/to/some/specific_string/specific_string.something/specific_string.something-else"
output=$(echo "$input_string" | sed "s/\(.*$variable\/\).*/\1/")
```

Output of variable output will be as follows.

```
echo $output
/path/to/some/specific_string/
```